# What tools can be used to download all images in a webpage?

Tags: download, javascript, web, css

I would like to download all images in a web page. The tool should be smart enough to examine the css and javascript files in the page source to look for the images.

Ideally, it should also replicate the folder hierarchy, saving the images in the correct folder. For example, the web page may have some images for menu items stored in images/menu/ and for background images it may be stored in images/bg/.

Is there such a tool that you know of? (preferably in Windows but Linux is still ok)

Many thanks to you all.

Comment: Please note that it would be impossible to do a 100% reliable job at this when arbitrary JavaScript is involved. Or for that matter, if any of the image URLs invoke server-side code (CGIs or whatnot) instead of just returning the same static image every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wGet for windows can recursively download a site. It should keep your folder structure. You may need to delete the html files after getting everything, but IMO, it's very easy to use.

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

use the "-r" flag to recursively download a site. 
e.g. `wget -r http://example.com`

Here's a brief tutorial on site downloading.

http://linuxreviews.org/quicktips/wget/

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Firefox, then the following add-ons will help:

[Save Images](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3404/)

> saves the images from the current tab
>   page, from the cache, to a specified
>   location, with either the images
>   original file name or a file name that
>   you specify. The size, dimensions and
>   types of images saved may be chosen,
>   with options if the file size is
>   unknown or if duplicate files are
>   found. Images may be either saved from
>   the current tab, left or right of the
>   current tab or from all tabs.

[DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201/)

This is a well-known add-on, possibly used together with [DownThemAll! AntiContainer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12577/).

> AntiContainer is an extension and
>   framework to DownThemAll! which allows
>   the user to download resources that
>   are normally hidden behind container
>   pages.
>
> For instance almost all so called
>   "one-click" image hosters, such as
>   imagevenue, use such container pages.
>   AntiContainer enables DownThemAll! to
>   download the actual images there
>   instead of just the page.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use a web spider such as WebReaper with a filter to only download .png, .jpg, .gif, etc. However, some sites block web spiders, so be aware.