# Is it possible to download all images in a PHP website?

Tags: images, php, download

I want to download all images from this website for art reference:

http://gbf-wiki.com/index.php?%BF%CD%CA%AA%B5%D5%B0%FA%A4%AD%B0%EC%CD%F7

But all image links are PHP links. This is the sample image URL:

http://gbf-wiki.com/index.php?plugin=attach&refer=img&openfile=3040011000_01full.png

HTTrack can download all html pages, but it does not detect these image files for some reason.

Comment: Does wget not work?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any knowledge about Wget. Can you provide any guideline to use this?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. What is the difference between HTTrack and Wget?

Comment: You can get the Windows version [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What tools can be used to download all images in a webpage?](http://superuser.com/questions/145549/what-tools-can-be-used-to-download-all-images-in-a-webpage)

Comment: This is different. This kind of image was returned from PHP script, not just from a directory which can be found by HTTrack.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using GetLeft. It is, in some ways, superior to HTTrack. Even though it froze halfway through, I gave it about 2-3 min and was able to download this image successfully.

Comment: Just tested again. GetLeft needed about 2 minutes and it unfroze on its own. I was able to get the whole PNG file.

Comment: I am trying GetLeft. It shows "Write Error" message.

Comment: I've never seen that error before. I'm assuming you have the latest version of GetLeft. Try a different output directory.

Comment: Changing directory doesn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to download the top link in your question with all the images, or the link below it which is an individual PNG?

Comment: I tried downloading another site. It was successful. Maybe it has something to do with the language.

Comment: I tried downloading the top link.

Comment: I was suggesting that maybe you can't download the whole site at once. I only tested the individual image link you provided. If all else fails, maybe uninstall GetLeft, reinstall, and if that fails, I would choose a previous version.

Comment: OK, here's another solution. It requires Liberty BASIC v4.5.0. This code worked for me:

Comment: open "C:\YourFolderHere\manga.png" for output as #file
print #file, httpget$("http://gbf-wiki.com/index.php?plugin=attach&refer=img&openfile=3040011000_01full.png")
close #file

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my comment for the lack of line breaks. I'll post the necessary code here:

open "C:\YourFolderHere\manga.png" for output as #file

'COMMENT: must delete line-break after "?" which was added by the web textbox
print #file, httpget$("http://gbf-wiki.com/index.php?plugin=attach&refer=img&openfile=3040011000_01full.png")

close #file

Comment: I suppose there is a misunderstanding here. I mean to download all image contents linked by this webpage at once, like site mirrorring or scraping, not some particular files.